# Add code to indicate no match found for usernames in my file that do not exist

Tags: powershell, active-directory

This PowerShell script will take a list of usernames from a file and export selected properties to a csv. It works great but I would like help to include the raw input from the text document, and I'm not sure how to add code to output NOMATCH into the csv for the usernames in my file that do not exist. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content Usernames.txt)) {

    Get-AdUser $user -Properties Name,displayname,Samaccountname,Surname,Mail,telephoneNumber,Department,Office,DistinguishedName,Enabled,Modified
        
}
    
 $users |
 Select-Object Name,displayname,SamAccountName,Surname,Mail,telephoneNumber,Department,Office,DistinguishedName,mail,Enabled,Modified |
 Export-CSV Username_To_DisplayName.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content Usernames.txt)) {

    try
    {
        Get-AdUser $user -Properties Name,displayname,Samaccountname,Surname,Mail,telephoneNumber,Department,Office,DistinguishedName,Enabled,Modified
    }
    catch
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{ Name = $user; displayname = 'NOMATCH' }
    }
}

$users |
Select-Object Name,displayname,SamAccountName,Surname,Mail,telephoneNumber,Department,Office,DistinguishedName,Enabled,Modified |
Export-CSV Username_To_DisplayName.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

There is a bug in your last statement, you reference 'mail' twice.

I personally execute such kind of task quite frequently, but take a slightly different approach. I don't use Export-CSV, but write my target file - which is technically just plain text - myself. This gives a much better flexibility adding exceptional content. Since CSV is somewhat cumbersome with respect to handling blanks and separator-chars within the text items I write a plain text file name.xls using a line format:

```
<textitem><tab><textitem><tab><textitem>...
<textitem><tab><textitem><tab><textitem>...
```

Excel complains at opening that this is a questionable format, but after positive confirmation it opens and displays as expected.

Comment: I noticed that after I already submitted my question lol. Good eye! This will work for me. I just changed the line to         [PSCustomObject]@{ SamAccountName = $user; Enabled = 'NOMATCH' }  so it's easier to filter. Good tip on the text but csv is so familiar to me. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to catch error when user not found.
try this :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content Usernames.txt)) {
 Try{
    Get-AdUser $user -Properties Name,displayname,Samaccountname,Surname,Mail,telephoneNumber,Department,Office,DistinguishedName,Enabled,Modified
   }
 catch {
   "$($user) not found"
  }
}
    
 $users |
 Select-Object Name,displayname,SamAccountName,Surname,Mail,telephoneNumber,Department,Office,DistinguishedName,mail,Enabled,Modified |
 Export-CSV Username_To_DisplayName.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: This one produces a csv with empty rows, presumably where usernames don't match something in AD. When I run the original script in ise, the error message is "Cannot find an object with identity: xxxx". An even better option for me would be to create each row in the csv with the username and I could see the raw input and deduct which ones had no match. Either way works :)

Comment: This is my fault, I did not test the script: the important thing is that you could have found a solution.